# jquery selectbox remove all options except two (selector variable name)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following select box

```
<select name="loc_id_1" id="loc_id_1">
<option value="PLS" selected="selected">-- PLEASE SELECT --</option>
<option value="NEW">-- ADD NEW --</option>
<option value="1">Smith Company</option>
<option value="6">Jones Company</option>
<option value="23">Wright Company</option>
</select>
```

There are multiple of these on the page  loc_id_2, loc_id_3,  etc all with different info.  I am using the following to detect a change in any of them.

```
$("[id^=loc_id_]").change(function(){
/// my magic code
var lc_id = $(this).attr('id');
my_function(lc_id,data1,data2);
});
```

This part works great.  The problem I am running into is as part of this code, I call a function that can refresh the data in the changed select box.  so I use the jquery remove function to refresh the selectbox

```
function my_function(id,d,f) {
var sel = $("#" + id);
sel.find('option[value!="NEW"] option[value!="PLS"]').remove();

// ajax code that calls database to append the other entries to the selectbox
}
```

The problem is, this removes the "ADD NEW" option, but leaves the "PLEASE SELECT" but my options from the database are added just fine.

Any idea how to fix this...

Comment: A few errors `}));` , `myfunction` - `my_function`

Comment: Shaunak,  I did not copy and paste my exact code, was just typing out the idea behind it.   But thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector will look for `descendant` inside the option element which is having the `value` NEW.Try,

```
sel.find('option[value!="NEW"][value!="PLS"]').remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6EB3/1/)

Comment: This removes all the values before my ajax re-adds the companies.

Comment: After finding an error in my HTML code, this solution does work.  Thanks alot.  I undated the jsfiddle as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/e6EB3/4/

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu Aravindasam, It was helpful for me.

Comment: Just wanted to say Thank You! I didn't know how this would be done and this really saved me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `:gt` selector

```
sel.find('option:gt(1)').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6EB3/)**

Comment: `gt()` is always require index.. `op` is trying to remove `element` by `value`.

Comment: @Girish: as you can clearly see the task can be achieved simply using modifying selector. then what is the need to make it complicated??

Comment: ok, but in case he want to remove 2 value `value="6"` and `value="1"` and he have not index of values then will `gt()` function work?

Comment: @Girish: dont be mom.he does not want that. i would have not provided the simplified solution then.

Comment: I was using the :gt selector with success on the first call, but additional calls to the routine (i.e. I select another option, was causing it to remove the options I wanted to keep.  Guessing because I am appending the data to the selectbox.

Comment: @Teeoney: it should work as long as you are not prep-ending anything before them or removing those two options. also you need to write this code in ajax success after appending options.